# How to connect Salesforce database in Django? Perform API calls using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, django, oauth-2.0, salesforce, django-salesforce

How to connect Salesforce database in django? Perform API calls using Python ?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'salesforce_db',
    },
    'salesforce': {
        'ENGINE': 'salesforce.backend',
        "CONSUMER_KEY" : 'EDIT: your key you get.......................',
        "CONSUMER_SECRET" : 'EDIT secret you get',
        'USER': 'EDIT your@user.login.name',
        'PASSWORD': 'EDIT password + security_token',
        'HOST': 'https://login.salesforce.com',
    }
}

SALESFORCE_QUERY_TIMEOUT= (4, 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

The System Administrator user can configure permissions for an application to use Salesforce API. Open Salesforce Lightning in a web browser, click **Setup > Apps > App Manager > New Connected App** (a button on the upper right corner).

You make a name of your application (or a name of a group of your applications that could be trusted/disabled together), fill some related required fields and click "**Enable OAuth Settings**" to see related settings. Select then the scope "Manage user data via APIs (**api**)" in "**Available OAuth Scopes**" and click "Save". You will see a "Consumer Key" and "Consumer Secret" for your application or you can see it later if you click "View" in "App Manager" at the end of your line.

I think that other details are good described in the documentation of [django-salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/django-salesforce/), but the upper right corner and Available OAuth Scopes are the most important details that will be added to this documentation so that the extensive documentation about [Salesforce - OAuth 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm) does not have to be read at all in the most simple case.